# How to change color of font?

Tags: sublimetext3

How to change color of certain type label of syntax?

I know that there is file of color scheme but what line of that file is related to colors of certain label (e.g. class or function).

For example, there is a piece of code in Sublime Text 3:

[image: Sample Code]

I do not want to see label 'Node' (that is class-label) yellow but want to see it blue. How I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you need to make a modification to the color scheme that you're using to tell it to color things in a different format. In particular, you need to know two things:

1. The color scheme that you're currently using.
2. The `scope` of the thing whose color you want to change.

To determine your color scheme, look in your preferences for the value of the `color_scheme` setting. Here I'm going to assume that it looks like this:

```
    "color_scheme": "Mariana.sublime-color-scheme",
```

Depending on how you set up the color scheme this might have part of a path as well, like `Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Mariana.sublime-color-scheme` instead. The file may also have a `tmTheme` extension instead of `sublime-color-scheme` if you're using a legacy color scheme.

To determine the `scope` you need to change, put the cursor on the thing whose color you want to change and use `Tools > Developer > Show Scope Name` (or press the key that menu tells you about), then make a note of what the last line of the popup says. In this case, we're assuming it is:

```
entity.name.class.c++
```

Your color scheme has a rule in it that tells it that things with a scope that matches this should appear the color that they do, so you need to adjust that color to be what you want.

To do that, you create a file in your `User` package, which you can locate by using `Preferences > Browse Packages...`. The file that you create should be the name of the color scheme you're using (just the filename, not the path if any) with an extension of `sublime-color-scheme` (even if the extension on your color scheme is `tmTheme`.

In our example, that means that we would create a file named `Mariana.sublime-color-scheme` in the `User` package.

The content of your file should look something like this:

```
{
    // http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/color_schemes.html
    "rules": [
        {
            "scope": "entity.name.class",
            "foreground": "var(blue)",
        },
    ]
}
```

This tells Sublime that for anything whose scope matches `entity.name.class`, it should use the color outlined by the variable `blue` instead of what your normal color scheme is doing. As soon as you save the file, you see the results appear.

We use `entity.name.class` here instead of `entity.name.class.c++` to make the `scope` match anything that's considered a class in any file. Basically the more of the scope from #2 above that you use, the closer the match will be. So if you use it all, it only affects C++.

The last thing to note here is that `var(blue)` will only work if your color scheme defines a variable named `blue`. The Mariana color scheme does, which is why I used that here. Yours may not, in which case you need to specify the color a different way.

The link in the example above points to the color scheme documentation with more details, but you could use something like `#0000FF` in place of `var(blue)` to get pure blue (adjust as required, that blue is likely far too dark).